# Adding component to Firemonkey custom styles at runtime

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, custom-component, delphi-xe6

I am making a custom list box for firemonkey.There I have customized a TSeachBox. In my custom style there is a TRectangle where i need to add TLabel at runtime.

I can add Lables at design time. But I can not see all the lables which are added at design time in this TRectangle. I've properly set the parent and owners of all the lables.

Any idea ?

below is the code :

```
procedure TCustomListBox.ColumnsChanged(Sender: TObject);
var  
  lPanel : TPanel;
  lLabel: TLabel;  
  iCount : Integer;
begin
  if Assigned(FSearchBox) then
  Begin     
    if FSearchBox.FindStyleResource('headerstyle') <> nil then
      lPanel := FSearchBox.FindStyleResource('headerstyle') as TPanel;

    if Assigned(lPanel) and (lPanel is TPanel) then
    begin
      //Clear all the columns except whose Tag = 1
      for iCount := lPanel.ChildrenCount - 1 downto 0 do
      begin
        if Assigned(lPanel.Children[iCount]) then
        begin
          if (lPanel.Children[iCount]).Tag = 0 then
            lPanel.Children[iCount].Free;
        end;
      end;
      iXPosition := 45;
      //FColumns1 is columns which needs to be added.
      for iCount := 0 to FColumns1.Count - 1 do
      begin
        FLabel := TLabel.Create(lPanel);
        FLabel.Parent:= lPanel;               
        FLabel.Name  := 'Col' + IntToStr(iCount);
        FLabel.Visible := True;
        FLabel.Position.X := iXPosition;
        FLabel.Align := TAlignLayout.alLeft;
        FLabel.Text  :=  FColumns1[iCount].ColumnHeaderText;
        FLabel.Width :=  FColumns1[iCount].ColumnWidth;
        iXPosition := iXPosition + FColumns1[iCount].ColumnWidth;       
      end;      
    end;
  End;
end;
```

Comment: "Please explain why the code (that I won't show you) is not working. Thanks." is not an answerable question here. If you want us to figure out why something isn't working for you, *include the code* so we can try to help.

Comment: I've edited the original post by adding code snippet.

Comment: Is there something related to Paint of the SearchBox. As when i tried binding a OnClick method and after clicking on searchbox on runtime, i can see the updates on runtime.